# version conflict error when using System.Data.SqlClient.dll in .Net Core 2.0

Tags: sqlclient, .net-core-2.0

I am getting version conflict error when using System.Data.SqlClient.dll in .Net Core 2.0. Its look like conflict between Core dll and NetStandard dll. Not sure why referring

> "System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.5.0.0

which was not existing.

Web application call Business library and in turn business library call DAL. DAL is using 
 System.Data.SqlClient.dll. All are in .Net Core2.0.

Can you please help?

Here is the error.

> 1> There was a conflict between "System.Data.SqlClient,
>   Version=4.2.0.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" and
>   "System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a". 1> "System.Data.SqlClient,
>   Version=4.2.0.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" was
>   chosen because it was primary and "System.Data.SqlClient,
>   Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" was
>   not. 1> References which depend on "System.Data.SqlClient,
>   Version=4.2.0.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
>   [C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\system.data.sqlclient\4.4.3\ref\netstandard2.0\System.Data.SqlClient.dll].
>   1> C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\system.data.sqlclient\4.4.3\ref\netstandard2.0\System.Data.SqlClient.dll
>   1> Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\system.data.sqlclient\4.4.3\ref\netstandard2.0\System.Data.SqlClient.dll".
>   1> C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\system.data.sqlclient\4.4.3\ref\netstandard2.0\System.Data.SqlClient.dll
>   1> References which depend on "System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.5.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" []. 1>
>   D:\Projects.Net Core\Test
>   Apps\Postsharp\SmartBank.Web\SmartBank.Core.Business\SmartBank.Core.Business\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\SmartBank.Core.DAL.dll
>   1> Project file item includes which caused reference "D:\Projects.Net
>   Core\Test
>   Apps\Postsharp\SmartBank.Web\SmartBank.Core.Business\SmartBank.Core.Business\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\SmartBank.Core.DAL.dll".
>   1> SmartBank.Core.Business 1> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2052,5):
>   warning MSB3277: Found conflicts between different versions of
>   "System.Data.SqlClient" that could not be resolved.   These reference
>   conflicts are listed in the build log when log verbosity is set to
>   detailed.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem: ORM library using `System.Data.SqlClient.dll` (version 4.6.0) directly but `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` transitively imports it as well with version 4.5.1.

I've switched the ORM library to using the same version as the one in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` but I'm a bit worried what happens when I upgrade